# How to launch WESTON with no input devices

Tags: wayland, buildroot, display-server

Been working on a project to create s simple digital display using the Raspberry pi 4 and buildroot.

It is a simple application that interacts with the user through bluetooth and displays some information on the attached HDMI screen.

All the debuging and programming work has been done. APP works fine

However after detaching the mouse and Keyboard; and setting up weston to launch automatically, it fails.
If i attach a keyboard and reboot, it works fine and weston is launched.

I did some digging and applied the configuration option `require-input=false` , but same problem.

Is there something i am missing ?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

After hours of experimenting, I found a work around, which might help others with into a similar issue.

In my application, I start my application by launching `weston` and passing my GTK application's absolute path as the parameter for the `client` option under the `[shell]` section in my `weston.ini` file.

To launch weston without inputs, I add the command line option `--continue-without-input`:

```
/usr/bin/weston --continue-without-input &
```